# Change min max color range on d3.scaleLinear().domain()

Tags: dc.js

How change min and max value in color range for dc.scatterPlot,

```
var heatColorMapping = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([1, hoursDaysGroup.top(1)[0].value/2, hoursDaysGroup.top(1)[0].value])
    .range(["rgb(17, 95, 154)", "rgb(118, 198, 143)", "rgb(208, 244, 0)"]);
```

when select new filter from dc.rowChart in dashboard - 
https://jsfiddle.net/gubzh/th4m5xwr/20/

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I found solution this problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038808/dc-js-heatmap-colour-range-not-getting-updated-after-filter-applied/36089246#36089246